# Unable to define typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass

I am trying to create a typeclass which adds sorted-merge functionality to lists.

```
trait SortedMerge[A, B[A] <: List[A]] {
  def sortedMerge(l1: B[A], l2: B[A]): B[A]
}

implicit val IntSortedMerge = new SortedMerge[Int, List[Int]] {
  override def sortedMerge(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def merge(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int], l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      (l1, l2) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => l
        case (Nil, _) => l ++ l2
        case (_, Nil) => l ++ l1
        case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) if (h1 < h2) => merge(t1, l2, l :+ h1)
        case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => merge(l1, t2, l :+ h2)
      }
    }

    merge(l1, l2, List[Int]())
  }
}


def sortedMerge[A, List[A]](l1: List[A], l2: List[A])
  (implicit merger: SortedMerge[A, List[A]]) = merger.sortedMerge(l1, l2)
```

I am getting the following error,

```
error: List[Int] takes no type parameters, expected: one
   val IntSortedMerge = new SortedMerge[Int, List[Int]] {
                                             ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because of this bound `[A, B[A] <: List[A]]`. Second type parameter should be higher-kinded type. So your code cold be rewritten in this way

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds

val IntSortedMerge = new SortedMerge[Int, List] {
  // stuff
}

def sortedMerge[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A])
  (implicit merger: SortedMerge[A, List]) = merger.sortedMerge(l1, l2)
```

**EDIT**

In your case you can actually drop second type parameter because you are expecting (?) only lists:

```scala
trait SortedMerge[A] {
  def sortedMerge(l1: List[A], l2: List[A]): List[A]
}

val IntSortedMerge = new SortedMerge[Int] {
  // stuff
}

def sortedMerge[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A])
  (implicit merger: SortedMerge[A]) = merger.sortedMerge(l1, l2)
```

But you also can weaken bound to something like `[A, B[A] <: Seq[A]]` which will allow you to build SortedMerge for any `Seq` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine:

```
trait SortedMerge[A, B <: List[A]] {
  def sortedMerge(l1: B, l2: B): B
}

implicit val IntSortedMerge = new SortedMerge[Int, List[Int]] {
    // ... omitted
}

def sortedMerge[A, B <: List[A]](l1: B, l2: B)
    (implicit merger: SortedMerge[A, B]) = merger.sortedMerge(l1, l2)
```

Usage:

```
println(sortedMerge[Int, List[Int]](List(2, 4), List(1, 3)))
```

Prints:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: that looks fine for now, but if you add in the omitted part you won't be able to solve it with the current signature of `sortedMerge`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: Why not? If I do `IntSortedMerge.sortedMerge(List[Int](1, 3), List[Int](2, 4))` it returns `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`, without any changes to the omitted part.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: When the `IntSortedMerge` is made `implicit`, it then works when calling the top level `sortedMerge[Int, List[Int]](List[Int](1, 3), List[Int](2, 4))` (i.e. not explicitly the one defined on `IntSortedMerge`, as in my previous comment).

Comment: that missing implicit was just a mistake when I was typing the question here.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: Clear, but what is not working then, with the `B <: List[A]` approach? You can see the result [on-line](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMX0JsU1RBUW8teWM).